# Привязка домена к новому хостингу

Tags: namespace, hosting, dns

Купил американский VPS у известного Godaddy.
Как по мне, очень сложная система управления. Куча аккаунтов и прочее.
Проблема в привязке домена, который был зарегистрирован у стороннего регистратора.
В тех.поддержке сказали, что нужно создать в панели WHM, свой личный Nameserver. Который как я понял, дальше нужно прописать у стороннего регистратора доменного имени.
Кто может подсказать как правильно это сделать - сейчас ничего не выходит.
Могу заплатить за работу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С godaddy всегда какие-то проблемы. 
Вот минимальная инструкция http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/652/creating-a-zone-file-for-your-domain-in-parallels-plesk-panel

Обычно ns прописываются у регистратора в таком виде:

ns1.yourdomain IP сервера
ns2.yourdomain IP сервера

Answer (score 1):

DNS. 
Например, http://blogobabki.ru/kak-privyazat-domen-k-xostingu/